# WKWebView Size fo HTML element Is Inconsistent Between iOS and MacOS

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I'm using a `WKWebView` in both the iOS and MacOS versions of my App. Both display the same HTML (generated within the APP by the same shared code) with the exception that on iOS this line is added to the `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=3.0, shrink-to-fit=NO, user-scalable=YES">
```

On MacOS the DOM inspector reports the correct page size (see image). And javascript run in the WKWebView reports the same size as shown by the DOM inspector for `document.documentElement.scrollWidth` and `document.documentElement.scrollHeight`

[image]

But, on iOS BOTH the DOM Inspector (looking at a device in debug mode) as well as the same javascript run in the `WKWebView` reports an incorrect size for the `<html>` element. The size it reports appear to be the visible viewport.

[image]
[image]

You can see from the second picture, which I scrolled a bit to the right, that the DOM inspector thinks `<html>` element is only as wide as the screen. This is presenting a real problem because I need to be able to get the correct page size via Javascript run IN the page via the `WKWebView` `evaluateJavaScript` function.

Interestingly though the `WKWebView.scrollView.contentSize` IS correct.

Any thoughts on what the heck is going on and how to resolve it?

**NEW INFO:
Adding css to the HTML element of `display:table` seems to help (display:block doesn't help). This doesn't seem to affect the macOS version of the pages and neither is it required but helps on iOS. This is a hack work around and doesn't resolve the actual problem and is likely not a suitable solution for everyone.**

**Probably A Bug
Bug report filed here: [Bug Report](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/9057027)**